# Counting Number of Activities until Specific = Conversation

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks

I am trying to count the number of Activities starting from Due Date = October 3rd, and I would like the counter to stop when an Activity occurs that has the Specific = Conversation.

For the latter portion I created a workflow to check box custom "Conversation Had" whenever Specific = Conversation.

But I am having trouble creating the Counter.  Here's the code I started off with:

```
trigger TaskConversationCount on Task (after insert, after delete, after undelete, after update){
set<id>accIds = new set <ID>();

if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.ISundelete){
for(Activity con: Trigger.new){
if(trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete || (act.Conversation_Had__c!=Trigger.oldMap.get(actId).Conversation_Had__c))

accIds.add(con.AccountId);
}
}
if(trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isDelete) {
for(Contact con:Trigger.old){
if(trigger.isDelete || (act.Conversation_Had__c != Trigger.newMap.get(actID).Conversation_Had__c))
accIds.add(con.AccountId);
}
}

if(!accIds.isEmpty()) {
List <Account> accList = [select id, Number_of_Activities__c, (Select Id, Conversation_Had__c from Task) from Activity
where ID IN: accIds];

 for(Account acc:AccList){
 system.debug('Activity--->'+acc.activities.size());
 acc.Number_of_Activities__c = 0;
 for(Activity con : acc.Task){
 if(con.Conversation_Had__c)
 acc.Number_of_Activities__c++;
 }
 }
 update accList;
 }
 }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you even able to save this trigger to start with ? Your trigger is on task object and you iterate over contacts? Also are you trying to show the count on another object like account/ contact ? where do you want this count to be displayed on?

Comment: No I was not able to save it; I am clearly new to APEX, just changing things around to see what works.

The number of activities I want to be displayed on the Account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically what you want is to implement a rollup summary field feature on account that can count the number of tasks, since rollups work only in a master detail context we cannot leverage that feature here. You figured out this part and started writing your code, good job on that. Take a look at Jeff's blog you may get more clarity on what the code does.

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/07/30/roll-up-summary-fields-with-lookup-relationships-part-1/

**Step 1:** Identify which object we need the count to be on. In our case the count should show up on Account.

**Step 2:** Start writing a trigger on task, when a task is inserted, update, deleted, undeleted we need the count on account to be updated.

```
trigger TaskConversationCount on task(after insert, after update, 
                                        after delete, after undelete) {

    List<Id> Accountids = new List<Id>();
    List<account> accountstoupdate = new List<account>();
    Integer countoftasksmatchingduedate = 0;
    date myoctober3date = date.newInstance(2016, 10, 03);


    if(trigger.new!=null){
        for(task tsk : trigger.new){
        Accountids.add(tsk.WhatId);
        }       
    }                

    if (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isDelete) {
        for (task item : Trigger.old)
            Accountids.add(item.WhatId);
    }

    Map<id,account> accountMap = new Map<id,account>([select id, Number_of_Activities__c from account where id IN :Accountids]);
    for (account acc: [select Id, Name, Number_of_Activities__c,(select id,ActivityDate from tasks) from account where Id IN :Accountids]) {
        for(task t: acc.tasks){
            if(t.ActivityDate == myoctober3date  ){
                countoftasksmatchingduedate = countoftasksmatchingduedate + 1;
            }
            accountMap.get(acc.Id).Number_of_Activities__c = countoftasksmatchingduedate;
        }
        Accountstoupdate.add(accountMap.get(acc.Id));
    }

update Accountstoupdate;

}
```

Comment: Hi Rao, thanks for this!  However, the number of Activities field i am still getting 0?
I changed the  date.newInstance(2016, 09, 22) for the purpose of testing.  I created 3 tasks today

Comment: Did you create tasks with due date = sep 09 2016. The code checks specifically if the due date fueld on task is same as the myoct03date variable.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean!
If I want tasks created from Oct 3rd and onwards, how would I update the trigger?

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: That is correct, if(t.ActivityDate == myoctober3date  ){ this line specifically checks if the duedate is same as the date variable, in a best case scenario i would say use a custom label/ custom setting and update the date as you want. Hardcoding is a very bad practice and you will have to deal with pain of pushing trigger from sandbox to Production all the time